# What are these small propellers in the A330 MRTT's wings?

Tags: military, propeller, airbus, airbus-a330, tanker

In actual flight there are small propellers rotating at the front of these "pillars". What are they? They are visible in this [video](https://youtu.be/bXW0ndvafks?t=290).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those two locations you circled out are the under-wing refuelling pods, mounted on pylons (where, I suspect, the A340 outboard engines would be).

You can find a picture of them on the [A330 MRTT Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A330_MRTT), under the Design section.

And those propellers on the pods are likely the ram air turbines that power the refuelling pods, [according to the manufacturer](https://www.cobham.com/mission-systems/air-to-air-refuelling/hose-and-drogue-systems/wing-air-refuelling-pods/):

> Wing-mounted aerial refuelling pods feature a drogue refuelling system and an integral fuel boost pump which provides a fuel transfer capability up to 450USGPM (1703 Litres per minute) at 45 to 55 PSI (310 to 379 kPa). Pods operate with aircraft power or are self-powered by a Ram Air Turbine.

Comment: You are correct about the location of the A330 refueling pods indeed -- the A330 MRTT uses the A340 wing for precisely that reason.

Comment: This is a very smart example of component-reuse. Put refueling pod onto the twin-engine A-330? Use the quad-engine A-340 wing. I guess this is an unexpected, positive consequence of the common development of the A-330 and A-340.

Comment: [RAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_air_turbine)